# A suitable replacement for *****double

Tags: c, list, dynamic, allocation, replace

I have this big data structure which is a list of lists of lists of lists of lists of doubles. Clearly it's extremely inefficient to handle. Around 70% of time spent to run my application is used to write zeros in the doubles at the end of the lists. I need a faster replacement which satisfies two constraints:

1)All the memory must be allocated continuously (that is, a huge chunk of memory)

2)I must access this chunk using the usual A[][][][][] syntax

As for now, I thought of using a *double to hold the entire chunk and reuse my list of lists of... to store pointers to the appropriate areas in the chunk.

Any better ideas?

Comment: May I ask why you need the huge chunk of memory?  A sparse matrix style representation would be a neat alternative where it not for this (and the `A[][][][][]` syntax!)

Comment: Why must you use the A[][][][][] syntax?  If you could relax this constraint, and replace it with a function call, like getValue(A,i,j,k,l,m), then I'm sure you can simplify your problem.

Comment: To clarify, when you say "list", you don't mean linked-lists?

Comment: @JeffFoster I need the chunk because my matrix is not sparse. Each element will be incremented by some value during computation

Comment: @Patrick I'm not the only developer. I'd like to allow other people to keep using the old syntax

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No. Sorry if I've caused confusion

Comment: **Around 70% of time spent to run my application is used to write zeros in the doubles at the end of the lists**. I dint understand this. Can you show us some snippet code where you define your array and where you zero it out?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ADZLtj5i

memget is just a calloc wrapper

Answer (score 0):

One example of how to achieve this with a 2D array, I'm to lazy to do the 5D case, is

```
double **a;
a = malloc (n * sizeof(*double));
a[0] = malloc (n * m * sizeof(double));
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
   a[i] = a[0][i*n];
```

This way you can decide if you wish to index it with a[0][i*n], or a[i][j]. The memory is contiguous, and you get away with only two allocations. Of course, this also requires a free n*m*sizeof(double) block in memory, but since you demand the memory to be allocated continuously I expect this to be satisfied. This also means that you will have to delete it correctly with:

```
free(a[0]);
free(a);
```

so I would make a create5Darray (n,m,k,l,t) and a delete5Darray function to make this easier.

Comment: please make your answer C, not C++

Comment: Interesting, but I'm working in C, so new and delete are a no go.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Edited the answer to C.